# Android Socket connection (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to connect from andriod to simple java server. Server is running and see connection if i do connect from adb `adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444`
 or even with pc ip `adb connect 192.168.1.104:4444`
but android get `java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`. PC and android is in single WIFI router.

MyServer

```
public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;
    private static String serverIp = "10.0.2.15";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            serverIp = getServerIp();

            if(serverIp != null){

                System.out.println("Listenning on IP:" + serverIp);

            }

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444  " + e.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

        while (true) {
            try {


                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection


                if(clientSocket.getInputStream().read() != -1){

                    System.out.println("Socket connection");

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Client disconected");

                }

                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                System.out.println(message);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading  " + ex.toString());
            }
        }

    }

    public static String getServerIp(){

        try{

            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
                    en.hasMoreElements();){
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAdress = intf.getInetAddresses();
                        enumIpAdress.hasMoreElements();){

                        InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAdress.nextElement();
                        if(!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()){

                            return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();

                        }

                    }

            }

        } catch (SocketException e){

            System.out.println(e.toString());

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

MyClient connection

```
public class ServerConnection extends AsyncTask<SocketAddress, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(SocketAddress... params) {

        try {

            mSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);//test ip
                            //192.168.1.104:4444 - real ip of the server returns the same

            PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(mSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write("this is test"); // write the message to output stream

            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();
            mSocket.close();

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Socket connecting to " + params[0].toString());

            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "===================ERROR====================" +
                    "\n" +
                    e.toString());

            return e.toString();

        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stas.clientserverconnection" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Exception is on `mSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444)` line

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your Manifest.xml file for your Android project?

Comment: see my edited manifest field

Comment: `mSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444)` You get an exception here because you don't have a server running on your phone at `127.0.0.1`. (probably).

Comment: yes but even i try to connect with my pc IP where server is running i get the same

Comment: Are you using a physical device or an emulator?

Comment: physical not rooted device 19 API

Comment: are your phone and computer (where the server program is running) on the same network?

Comment: Switch off the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are ok but the problem is indicated by @JonasCz

```
mSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444)
```

You don´t have access to `127.0.0.1` from your device!

Comment: yes, but when i'm using address of my PC where server is `192.168.1.104:4444` i've got the same exception

Answer (score 0):

[Android Client and Java Desktop Communication using Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304249/android-client-and-java-desktop-communication-using-socket) (worked for me)
**BEST SOLUTION**
You are trying to make network communication on the main thread, which is not permitted on Android 4.0+. To solve the crash just move your code to another Thread (You should have a look at AsyncTask for example).

You can do something like that:

private class SendMessage implements Runnable {
    private String mMsg;

```
public SendMessage(String msg) {
    mMsg = msg;
}

public void run() {
    try {

        client = new Socket("localhost", 7575);  //connect to server
        printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
        printwriter.write(messsage);  //write the message to output stream

        printwriter.flush();
        printwriter.close();
        client.close();   //closing the connection

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
And then change the onClick to this:

```
    public void onClick(View v)  
       { 
       messsage = textField.getText().toString();

       textField.setText("");      //Reset the text field to blank new

       Thread(new SendMessage(message)).start();    // start a new thread to make the communication in the background
```

}